# Execute Python Script (spyder) from Excel using VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, interaction, blpapi

I have a problem regarding the question's title:

A quick intro to my situation: I'm using python within spyder and my Code (multiple hundred lines) includes a bloomberg-python api. Because I'm using multiple tickers, the code's execution time is about 24sec. The code will import some data from the same sheet I want to execute the python code from. In the end, the code will write some data into a different Excel document.
Simply said: Python code pulls data from Excel doc A, process the data and writes it to Excel doc B. In the end, Excel doc A pull's data from Excel doc B.

I've read and watched nearly all articles/videos about this topic (none of it solved my prob) and currently using the following code within VBA:

```
Sub RunPythonScript()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath As String, PythonScriptPath As String
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
'    PythonExePath = Chr(34) & "C:\Users\Anaconda3\python.exe" & Chr(34)
'    PythonScriptPath = Chr(34) & "C:\Users\test.py" & Chr(34)
    PythonExePath = """C:\Users\Anaconda3\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\test.py"""

    
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
    Application.Goto Reference:="RunPythonScript"

End Sub
```

I've tried both ways regarding PythonExePath and PythonScriptPath (so the commented part and the uncommented part). I've also added the waitOnReturn and windowStyle part.

PROBLEM: The VBA code runs without errors, but the python code won't be executed in spyder. There is just a quick blink of a black window.

THX!

Answer (score 0):

Does the python code depend on the working directory in which it is run? i.e. does it find excel A using a relative path?

Because if this is the case, then maybe the python script being executed in the VBA code is using a different directory from the one you have used when you were developing and testing your code.

I am not familiar with VBA, but you can try changing directory in the shell you start in the VBA code. Otherwise, I would suggest you create a batch file that runs your python script as expected (remember to include a change of directory), and then use VBA to launch that batch file.

Or even more simply, just use an absolute path in your python code.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I'm not quite sure what you mean with your first two questions. So, the .py doc lays within the same folder as the Excel A and Excel B. You think this could cause a problem?